# CloudWatch Event Trigger Rule (State Change OK)

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create a state change to OK rule for my specific CloudWatch  Alarms these are the metrics for which i need the rule to be applied - (Disk, Memory, CPU, ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage). I have more than 500 alarms for which one by one I cant manually add OK notification. and also I cant add the rule directly to all the CloudWatch Alarms as there are multiple Alarms we have added.

I want it to be triggered only for specific metrics (Disk, Memory, CPU, ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage)

I have tried multiple rules but they did not worked can anyone please provide so it will trigger the Alarms when the state changes to OK for specific metrics (Disk, CPU, Memory, ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage).

Note - these are not alarm names these are just the metrics for which I need the OK alarm to be triggered (disk_used_percent, CPUUtilization, mem_used_percent, ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage ).